# as3 Error #2007 jigsaw puzzle

Tags: actionscript-3

iv been working on a basic puzzle on as3 adobe flash and i came across #2007 Error. the weird thing is i did a practice version of the jigsaw with the exact same code and didnt have any problems. the full Error is:

TypeError: Error #2007: Parameter hitTestObject must be non-null.
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/_hitTest()
    at flash.display::DisplayObject/hitTestObject()
    at jigsawfinaltester_fla::MainTimeline/JigSaw()

Comment: additional information :i copied and replaced the movieclips in jigsaw 3 with the jigsaw final tester and the 2007 error poped up and i did vice versa and the error doesn't pop up on final tester with jigsaw 3 movieClips

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the jigsaw_3.fla:

- "jig1" contains MovieClip with the "Jlink1" name.
- "jig2" contains MovieClip with the "Jlink2" name.
- ...

In Your jigsaw_final_tester.fla:

- "jig1" contains MovieClip with the "Jlink3" name.
- "jig3" contains MovieClip with the "Jlink4" name.
- ...

Correct names of Jlink's.
ID of "Jlink" must match the ID of the "jig".

Comment: After calling hitTestObject set the correct position of "jig".

Example:

`if ( Blink2.hitTestObject(jig2.Jlink2))
{
 jig2.x = Blink2.x;
 jig2.y = Blink2.y;
 end2 = 1;
 ender();
}`